# Can someone tell me how to fix my audio problems? I've tried multiple solutions but none of them worked. My computer system is Ubuntu hp 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, soundcard

No output or input devices were found. Pressing the mute button and volume buttons are completely useless. Installing packages seem to not work either as it ends up saying that it couldn't find the source.

[image]